# What's the difference between intentionality and meaning?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, semantics, intentionality

Intentionality is for something to be *about* something. But this definition could also suffice for meaning: something can have meaning if it is *about* something. What is the major distinction between intentionality and meaning? I understand that different philosophers treat the concepts of intentionality and meaning differently, so I'm mainly looking for broad intuition here.

Comment: Who specifically are you reading? "Broad intuition" is not going to be very helpful here.

Comment: Brentano and Dennett specifically, but my confusion seems to apply to all philosophers talking about intentionality haha

Comment: One possible distinction (and I think according to e.g. Kant and Husserl) is that intentionality is an *act* of a *subject* while meaning is a *property* of a *linguistic expression*, may it be a sentence, term or "concept". That is quite a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A first reference is SEP:

Concerning intentionality see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/
Accordingly

> Intentionality is the power of minds to be about, to represent, or to stand for, things, properties and states of affairs.

Concerning meaning see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/
Accordingly meaning is a property of words, sentences and - more general - symbols of a language:

> The first sort of theory - a semantic theory - is a theory which assigns semantic contents to expressions of a language. [...] The second sort of theory - a foundational theory of meaning - is a theory which states the facts in virtue of which expressions have the semantic contents that they have.

Comment: So the main distinction here is the domain of discourse?

Comment: Yes. But I am sure that not everybody subscribes to this strict separation. Let's wait for further answers :-)